# CSS Behavioral difference in React18

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, frontend, documentation

CSS styling is behaving differently for strict-mode and non strict-mode. for example:-

```
class*="MuiButtonBase-root-MuiButton-root"
```

works in strict mode but has to change it to

```
class*="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root"
```

for it to work without strict mode.
These Behavioral difference are there only  after upgrading the version to React18. The official documentation for version upgrade doesn't say anything about changes in CSS. Anyone have any idea why this is happening or have any documentation related to CSS behavior difference with React18.

```
                                                   thanks
```